# Disadvantages of xcode 3.1.2

Tags: ios, xcode

and in ios development. And I'm currently working on xcode 3.1.2, my question is what is the difference if I develop an IOS app in xcode 3.1.2, are there disadvantages is I used it since it is an older version of xcode.? Does it support all platform?

Comment: You did some research yourself? Or you are directly asking question on SO?

Comment: if you use this then main disadvantage is you can not make app with iPhone 5 competible, and you can not use latest features.

Comment: When it was launched It was the best XC ever. Now you have XCode6 having new string literals, support to new ios, better gui, no IB as an extra application etc etc

Comment: @AnoopVaidya where did you get XCode 6 from??

Comment: I think @AnoopVaidya has mixed XCode and iOS versions.....

Comment: Oops XC4.6 missed 4 :(

Answer (score 1):

The main disadvantage is you can't use the latest SDK, so you can't send apps to the app store.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all added/removed features since Xcode 4.0 here: [Xcode Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/index.html). Check them and learn if you want or don't want to update.

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods which gets depreciated with the newer version of the software. So, same is the case with xcode 3.1.2. project create in xcode 3.1.2 may work in higher platform but you don't get all functionality. One example I have, device orientation. xcode 3.1.2 orientation methods are not supported in higher version(methods are updated in higher version). This is the only one example. You should go for latest version, if there is no specific reason for using older version.